# Excel: Font in Chart Corrupts Excel File

Tags: excel, charts

Excel files with a chart using the "Futura Bold" font fail to open, throwing this error message:
[image: "We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?"]
Selecting "Yes" results in this message: 
[image: "Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.]
Clicking "View" opens an XML document with this summary of what was deleted:

```
<removedParts summary="Following is a list of removed parts:"><removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)</removedPart></removedParts>
```

The same condition occurs on both Mac and Windows. Using Excel for Mac v16.10.

### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new Excel file and sample data.
2. Insert a new bar chart and select your sample data.
3. Add a chart title to your chart.
4. Change the font for the title to "Futura Bold".
5. Save the file, close Excel.
6. Open the file. Error messages.

When the file is opened, charts have been removed.

I have many Excel files that use this font, not looking forward to having to re-create each one. Unclear if it's this particular font, or others cause the condition. Curious this affects both OS X and Windows. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Futura exactly? I don't mean weight (Light, Bold, etc...) but the Foundry you got it from (there are several Futuras on the market)

Comment: This version of Futura comes installed with OS X (and Windows?), I did not install the font from a foundry.